# How to remove "accents" from strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, replace, f#

I want to write a F# or C# function that removes Spanish accents from a string like so:

```
in: "a stríng withóut áccents"
->  
out: "a string without accents"
```

I know how to achieve this in Python 3:

```
trans_table =  str.maketrans( "áéíóúñÁÉÍÓÚÑàèìòùäëïöü", "aeiounAEIOUNaeiouaeiuo" )
# trans_table now contains a dictionary: { "á" : "a", "é" : "e", ... }
"A stríng withóut áccents".translate( trans_table )
# result is: A string without accents
```

Mimicking this solution would be rather straight forward if the characters to be translated where regular ascii characters (in the 0-127 range).  However, because of the way .NET encodes strings it doesn't seem straight forward to do it for actual unicode characters out of this range...

I would like a solution that does not imply doing a regex-replace for each one of the many accented characters but that hopefully loops over the string only once...

Any ideas?

Comment: Two duplicates shows how you should do that and how you'd do that to match you Python implementation.